# Not able to load Cell from XIB iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When I try to load cell via `XIB` then app get crashed and give me following exception.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSUnknownKeyException`, reason: `[<MyAdsViewController 0x7a38e30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:` this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key carousel.

Can anybody help to out from this issue.

Comment: are you trying to add customize cell ?

Comment: post your code here so that we can correct you if needed

Comment: Hey Guys, thx for you favourable response. As there is one iboutlet set to wrong view. Now, its working. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ::

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell.
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"customCell";
    customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib;
        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id oneObject in nib)
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[customCellr class]])
               cell = (customCell *)oneObject;

        cell.title.text = @"Hello";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Yupp, if there is exception then app is not crushed with your code. thx man

Comment: Pleasure to help you.. Enjoy Coding..:)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to go to `XIB` of this class, and check for any thing with warning of linking, like this [image].

Remove these type of links then run your application.

Answer (score 0):

try to create object for cell  and follow the below code u able do it

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { static NSString
*simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

ISOPriceCell *cell = (ISOPriceCell *)[tableview_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; if (cell
== nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ISOPriceCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.priceTextFiled.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    cell.priceTextFiled.delegate = self;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;}}
```